# Getting "Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found" in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm quite new to Laravel and when I am going through a tutorial when I encountered this error. This is my code in 'testController.php'.

```
<?php

namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use app\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class testController extends \app\Http\Controllers\Controller {

public function getAbout()
{
    return view('Learning.about') ;
}

public function getHome()
{
    return view('Learning.index');
}

}
```

And this is my 'routes.php'.

```
<?php
Route::get('test', [
   'as' => 'test', 
   'uses' => 'testController@getHome',
]);

Route::get('about', [
    'as' => 'about', 
    'uses' => 'testController@getAbout',
]);
```

I am getting this error:

> Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you generating via php artisan or you just created manually ? Can you try like php artisan make:controller TestController. So, you don't need to worry about namespace. It will be automatically generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step.

#### 1. Check autoload directive on composer.json

Open `composer.json` file on your project root directory. Locate the the `autoload` section. It should be looking like this:

```
{
    ...
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
}
```

Make sure you have this configuration under the `psr-4` option:

```
"App\\": "app/"
```

This configuration tells the composer that we want to autoload all classes inside the `app` directory using [psr-4](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) convention and places it under the `App` namespace.

#### 2. Update your controller

First, your controller file name should be in CamelCase style. So we have to renamed it to `TestController.php`. Make sure that it's saved under `app/Http/Controllers` directory.

Now open your `TestController.php` file, we have to capitalize the namespace and class name like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {
    public function getAbout()
    {
        return view('Learning.about') ;
    }

    public function getHome()
    {
        return view('Learning.index');
    }
}
```

Note that we also turn this line:

```
class testController extends \app\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

Into:

```
class TestController extends Controller
```

Since we already import the base `Controller` class, we don't have to specify the fully qualified name. We imported the `Controller` class using the `use` keyword:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

Save your `TestController.php` file.

#### 3. Update your routes file

Now we have to update our `app\Http\routes.php` file. We just need to capitalize the controller name:

```
<?php

Route::get('test', ['uses' => 'TestController@getHome', 'as' => 'test']);

Route::get('about', ['uses' => 'TestController@getAbout', 'as' => 'about']);
```

#### 4 Update your autoloader

Now the last thing to do. Open your terminal / command prompt. Go to your project directory and run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This command will update the autoloader file ([Read more here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload)).

Now if you open up your browser and hit `/test` route, you should see the content from `resources/views/Learning/index.blade`.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct namespace:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// Remove: use app\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class testController extends Controller {
```

Comment: You controller is in `app\Http\Controllers`, right?

Comment: Yes it is in the Controllers, same with 'testController'.

Comment: Did you remove `use app\Http\Controllers\Controller;` line?

Comment: Yes I did but didn't do any difference. By the way, I just noticed that my Controller.php has the path 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Controller.php'. Does it affect here to the code ?

Comment: If you still getting `app\..` message, then you didn't remove the line or didn't change namespace or `extends` part. The code above is from standard Laravel controller. Double check everything.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience in Laravel projects, the namespaces starts with the capital `A` of `App` used in namespace, you should try to change your code to this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class testController extends Controller { }
```

Also check if the controller - `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` lies in the same namespace as mentioned in your code.

Comment: Actually the Controller.php lies as 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Controller.php'. I don't think it makes any difference to the name space, do it ?

Comment: I think the casing of letters differ according to different OS, like in mac it reacts to be right else in Ubuntu it reacts to be wrong, etc for other OS too

Answer (score 0):

Include this at the top of your Controller file. This fixed it for me.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the problem is that the framework is not able to instantiate your given controller class. This can happen for example if you are using a sub-folder under `Controllers` and that when you are extending the `Controller.php` class, you did not provide the `use` statement to that definition*. Other run-time errors may also cause this.

*Which is now required since your own controller is not at the root of the `Controller` folder anymore.